# Porting Windows Phone7 application to Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-7.1

I ported my windows phone7 application to windows 8(just copy paste the xaml and c# code in visual studio 2012->new->project->WPFApplication) and made changes in UI sizes.The problem is the .exe file(after building wpf application) runs only in the system with .NET framework installed.I want to run my application in all system running windows(7(32/64),xp,vista).I am newbie to windows application basically wp7 developer.Thank u.

Comment: windows 8 app and wpf app are not the same. Windows 8 refers to metro style apps.

Comment: @MilanAggarwal   
Does Metro style app runs on all windows 8 devices(surface,PC,WinRT Tablets)

Comment: Metro style apps are now called Microsoft Store Apps, and yes they will run on all Win 8 devices.

Comment: Yes. They will. More information in my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF is a part of the .NET framework, so you can't write a WPF application that can run without the framework on the machine.

If you want to create a binary that run on the classic windows runtime you can't use WPF/C#/VB etc.

Best thing if you want to port your Windows Phone app to Windows 8 is to create a Microsoft Store app, *File > New Project > Blank App in VS2012*. The app won't run on anything except Windows 8 but the Microsoft Store for Windows 8 is probably the best place to have your app if it's ported from Windows Phone.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to port a windos phone 7 app to windows 8, You should go through the following resources. They provide most of the information.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465136.aspx
- http://leventoz.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/moving-a-windows-phone-app-to-windows-8-a-case-study-part-1/
- http://leventoz.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/moving-a-windows-phone-app-to-windows-8-a-case-study-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

Migrating application to WP7 is not that easy as it sounds. There is lot of different APIs and also limited async/await in WP7 when using [this extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx).
I would probably recommend starting with this MSDN article. It describes basic problems and challenges and also contains useful namespace and API mapping:
[Migrate/port a Windows Phone 7 app to a Windows Store app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh465136)